# call onclick method from c#

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, onclick

I want to call onclick in C#. I put a WebBrowser to C# based program and in website, there is a button tied with a `js` function

```
type="button" 
onclick="submitEdgeStory();" 
value="Invia la news" class="submit"
```

I want to call `onclick` method. I tried to call `submitEdgeStory` with:

```
 webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("submitEdgeStory()");
```

or

```
 webBrowser1.Document.Forms[1]
                     .SetAttribute("onclick", "return submitEdgeStory()");
```

but no way.. I dont know how can I call this function...

PS: I am not using `ASP.NET`. It's just a desktop application

And also this is js function

```
var gPageIsOkToExit = false;

    function submitEdgeStory()
    {
        // Set a variable so that our "before unload" exit handler knows not to verify
        // the page exit operation.
        gPageIsOkToExit = true;

        // Do the submission.
        // var frm = document.getElementById("thisform");
        frms = document.getElementsByName("ATISUBMIT");

        if (frms)
        {
            if (frms[0])
                frms[0].submit();
        }
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function (event) 
    {
        // See if this is a safe exit.
        if (gPageIsOkToExit)
            return;

        if (!event && window.event) 
                event = window.event;

        event.returnValue = "You have not hit the Submit Button to submit your story yet.";
    }
```

Comment: Which WebBrowser are you using? The WinForms one, the WPF one, or the Silverlight one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like that way

```
        foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.All)
        {
            if ( item.OuterHtml != null)
            {
                if (item.OuterHtml.Contains("submitEdgeStory"))
                {

                    item.InvokeMember("click");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assign an id to your button

```
type="button" 
onclick="submitEdgeStory();" 
value="Invia la news" class="submit" id="buttonid"
```

then you could do-

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("buttonid").InvokeMember("submit")
```

Comment: when I did it,I got this message  http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1476/errc.png

Comment: Try - `webBrowser1.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("Submit")`, does that give the same result?

Comment: Probably a silly question, but, do you get a different result if you click the button?

Comment: when i click the button in webbrowser manually, it works.. if you mean this question? when I click OK, then it works too

Answer (score 0):

`webBrowser.Document.Forms[0].All.GetElementsByName("buttonname")[0].InvokeMember("click");` should work fine.

Comment: heyy thanx it works :) but I dont know button name then I used            [code]List<HtmlElement> hl = new List<HtmlElement>();
            string s ="";
            foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.All)
            {
                hl.Add(item);
                s = item.GetAttribute("value");
                     if(s =="Invia la news")
                     {
                         item.InvokeMember("click");
                         break;
                     }

            }[/code]    but s =="Invia la news"  is not good for coding..